# Apache Commons Logging with Logback

Tags: logback, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

I have a Java web application that was using Log4j 1.x, which I migrated to slf4j using logback. I have a logback.xml file that includes my appenders, which are used by slf4j log statements such as the following:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

logger.info("slf4j using logback message");
```

However, I have some commons-logging in the code as well, declared as follows:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);

log.info("commons logging message");
```

To my surprise, these statements also use my appenders declared in logback.xml (based on matching formatting in the logs). Why would this be? Does apache commons logging look at logback.xml?

At first I thought this had to do with the fact that I have jcl-over-slf4j being brought in as a transitive dependency in my pom.xml. But even after I exclude that, it appears commons logging is still using logback.xml. Is this expected? If so, is it possible to declare an appender in logback.xml that specifically formats statements using commons-logging?